# React & Python with numpy?

Tags: python, reactjs, numpy

Can you use Python in the backend while still utilzing modules like numpy, with React.js on the frontend in the same project for a fullstack application?

Comment: Yes, you can use python to generate an API and communicate react with this, while still using in the API any feature of python that you need.

Comment: Where can I find an example of how to do this?

Comment: You would not be able to call the numpy lib directly from react/javascript code, you would have to interact with it via a network request.

Comment: You can use Django in the backend and React, you can find a lot of documentation about how to do this, after that you will be able to use numpy in the backend and in the frontend you need to communicate with a backend API.